# Multi-threading writing to multiple distributed tables in a DolphinDB database

Tags: concurrency, dolphindb

I tried to conduct concurrent writes in DolphinDB and set `enableChunkGranularityConfig = true`. I have three tables, `oq`, `mk`, `ts`, all under the `1db3tb` database. I want to write data to these tables and test the concurrent performance. How to write a dos command to conduct concurrent writes?

I created a dos file as follows, but it seems still single-threaded. How can I append data to the tables at the same time?
`tableObj1.append!(t1)`
`tableObj2.append!(t2)`
`tableObj3.append!(t3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following script:

```
def writeData(dbName, tableName, data){
    timer loadTable(dbName, tableName, data){
}
submitJob("write1", "write data", writeData, dbName, tableName1, data1)
submitJob("write2", "write data", writeData, dbName, tableName1, data2)
submitJob("write3", "write data", writeData, dbName, tableName1, data2)
getRecentJobs()
```